# Why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}1=n*(n-1)/2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

This summation came up because I wanted to calculate the number of terms in this set $$\{(i,j) | i > j; i,j = 1,...n\}$$

The summation is equivalent to the number of terms right?

Answer (score 3):

Just change the order of your summation:
 $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n 1= \sum_{j=2}^n \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} 1 = \sum_{j=2}^n {(j-1)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: You have $j \ge i+1$ so $i \le j-1$ so the second inside sum should go to $j-1$, not $j$. Note that $\sum_{i=0}^j 1 = j+1$, which would gove you an incorrect value.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistakes, I have corrected it.

Comment: Your second inner sum should go to $j-1$; otherwise $\sum_{j=1}^n j = n(n+1)/2$, the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{(i,j) | i > j; i,j = 1,...n\}$, $B=\{(i,j) | i < j; i,j = 1,...n\}$ and $C=\{(i,j) | i = j; i,j = 1,...n\}$.

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are mutually disjoint and $A\cup B\cup C=\{(i,j) | i,j = 1,...n\}$.

By symmetry, We have $|A|=|B|$.

\begin{align*}
|A|+|B|+|C|&=|\{(i,j) | i,j = 1,...n\}|\\
2|A|+n&=n^2\\
|A|&=\frac{n^2-n}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is just compute the number of ways to take two distinct numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, which is counted by binomial coefficient ${n\choose 2}=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$.

Comment: Ah interesting. But is this still the same with the restriction that i > j?

Comment: Yes. Maybe think this way: first leave out the restriction $i>j$. There are $n$ choices for the first number, and $n-1$ choices for the second number. Then reintroduce $i>j$ by dividing by 2 to factor out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^n1=n-(i+1)+1=n-i$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=?$$ setting $n-i=k$

Comment: Ah i see. I think you mean that Sum 1 = n - (i + 1) + 1, correct?

Comment: @Goldname, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Geometric answer to counting the number of terms in the set
$$
   U = \{ (i,j) : i > j, i,j = 1 \dots n \}
$$
Mark the locations $(i,j)$ for $i=1\dots n-1$,$j=1 \dots n$. Notice that $U$ occupies half of the marked locations and that there are $n(n-1)$ locations marked.